# How to sort an array that includes NaN's C

Tags: c, nan, bubble-sort

Have been trying to implement my code as a means to sort all integers including NaNs. However can not seem to find a function that would sort NaNs into my program. Code is able to sort other integers including infinities, however when a nan is entered the program recognizes the input but does not sort it to the start of the list. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float array[100], swap;
    int c, d, n;

    printf("Enter the size of array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
        scanf("%f", &array[c]);

    for (c = 0; c < (n - 1); c++)
    {
        for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++)
        {
            if (array[d] > array[d + 1]) 
            {
                swap = array[d];
                array[d] = array[d + 1];
                array[d + 1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Sorted array in ascending order:\n");


    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
        printf("%f\n", array[c]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  Your code is straight C code.

Comment: Make your if more complicated. if (array[d] != Nan && array[d+1] == NaN || ...) -- something like that, so you leave leading NaN values where they are and shift later ones towards the front.

Comment: @NathanOliver My bad was corrected by someone else yeah its definitely C code. Dont know why it worked using scanf and all in the cpp file but ill go ahead and change the title name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your code is C code and not C++. Here is your code in C++ with an added condition which should fix your problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::size_t array_size;
    std::cout << "Enter the size of array\n";
    std::cin >> array_size;

    std::cout << "Enter " << array_size << " integers\n";

    std::vector<float> array(array_size);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i)
        std::cin >> array[i];

    for(std::size_t a = 0; a < array.size() - 1; ++a)
        for(std::size_t b = 0; b < array.size() - 1 - a; ++b)
            if(std::isnan(array[b + 1]) || array[b] > array[b + 1])
                std::swap(array[b], array[b + 1]);

    std::cout << "Sorted array in ascending order:\n";

    for(const auto& a : array)
        std::cout <<  a << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

And if you don't want to write all the sort stuff by yourself, you can do it with even more C++ and the algorithm library (and an added input check):

```cpp
template<typename T>
T get_input()
{
    T input;
    while(true)
    {
        std::cin >> input;
        if(std::cin)
            return input;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Invalid input! Please try again.\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the size of array\n";
    std::size_t array_size = get_input<std::size_t>();

    std::cout << "Enter " << array_size << " integers\n";

    std::vector<float> input(array_size);
    for(auto& a : input)
        a = get_input<float>();

    std::sort(input.begin(), input.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b){ return std::isnan(a) || a < b; });

    std::cout << "Sorted array in ascending order:\n";

    for(const auto& a : input)
        std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help! My bad dont know why the code worked in C++ but yeah my code was definitely C forgot about the std::cout function. In regards to the given code have used it through visual studio, would there be a way to add more than one NaN. Currently when typing NaN in the console all remaining arrays become 0, without the option of typing another number.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. `std::cin` will fail if you input "NaN" because that's no float. As soon as the fail flag of `std::cin` is set, it will skip all other input operations until you clear the flag using `std::cin.clear()` (see the second code example). Using `std::cin` it is impossible to input NaN directly into a float, you'd have to use a string and convert the string into a float. You would have to input the NaN manually using either C's `nanf("")` or C++'s `std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN()`.
But actually, why do you want to input a NaN?

Comment: Part of a project, requirement is to input a NaN @Unterfliege

Comment: If `a` and `b` are both NaN, the comparison should return false (otherwise the conditions for weak ordering are violated).  So to be safe, the comparison should be `!std::isnan(b) && (std::isnan(a) || a < b)`.

Answer (score 3):

Note that according to the C standard, two NaN values never compare equal, even if they have the same bit pattern.  If you are going to sort data with NaNs, you need to:

1. Decide where NaN values should be sorted w.r.t proper values (typically the choices are "before negative infinity" or "after positive infinity").
2. Use much more delicate tests than a simple `a > b` comparison.

You can find relevant information scattered around the C11 standard.  For example:

- [§7.12.14 Comparison macros](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.14)
- [§5.2.4.2.2 Characteristics of floating point types `<float.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.2)
- [§6.2.6.1 Representations of types: General ¶4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.1p4)
- [§6.3.1.2 Boolean type](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.2)
- [§7.12.3 Classification macros](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.3)
- [§7.12.3.4 The `isnan` macro](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.3.4)
- [§7.12.3.6 The `signbit` macro](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.3.6)
- [§7.12.12.2 The `fmax` functions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.12.2)
- [Annex F: IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic (normative)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#F)

You will probably arrange to create a function (possibly an `inline` function, unless you're going to pass it to a function like `qsort()`) that compares two floating point values of the relevant type (it looks like you're using `float`) that uses the `isnan()` or `isnanf()` classification macro to determine whether either or both of the values is a NaN.  The function will probably return a value indicating equality if both values are NaNs, but if one is a NaN, the return value will place it earlier or later than the other depending on the order in which you want NaNs to appear, and it will return the appropriate value for the comparison of other values (normal values, zeros, infinities, subnormal numbers) — regular values and infinities only require the regular comparison operators unless you need to sort negative zeros correctly w.r.t positive zeros.

For example, writing a function that works with `qsort()` (and using type `double` rather than `float`) yields something like this, assuming that numbers should be sorted into ascending sequence and that NaNs should compare smaller than any other value.  The code includes test code to read data from standard input, print it, sort it, and print it again.

```
#include <math.h>

/* Belongs in a header! */
extern int cmp_double(const void *v1, const void *v2);

/* Sort doubles, with NaNs coming first */
/* Switch return values -1 and +1 after testing n1, n2 to sort NaNs last */
int cmp_double(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    double d1 = *(const double *)v1;
    double d2 = *(const double *)v2;
    int n1 = isnan(d1);
    int n2 = isnan(d2);

    if (n1 && n2)
        return 0;
    if (n1)
        return -1;
    if (n2)
        return +1;
    if (d1 < d2)
        return -1;
    if (d1 > d2)
        return +1;
    // The values are 'equal', but …
    if (d1 != 0.0)
        return 0;
    // They're both zero, but they could have different signs
    int s1 = signbit(d1);
    int s2 = signbit(d2);
    if (s1 != s2)
        return (s1) ? -1 : +1;
    return 0;
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void dump_doubles(const char *tag, int num, double values[num])
{
    printf("%s (%d):\n", tag, num);
    int line_len = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        int n = printf(" %+12.4f", values[i]);
        if (n <= 0)
            break;
        line_len += n;
        if (line_len >= 60)
        {
            line_len = 0;
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
    if (line_len > 0)
        putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    enum { NUM_VALUES = 50 };
    double values[NUM_VALUES];

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALUES; i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%lf", &values[i]) != 1)
            break;
    }

    dump_doubles("Before sort", i, values);
    qsort(values, i, sizeof(values[0]), cmp_double);
    dump_doubles("After sort", i, values);

    return 0;
}
```

Note the testing required to sort -0.0 before +0.0!

Consider the input data:

```
3023.421800 9033.902200 nan -9370.952500 3088.884900 6829.135400 0
-0.000000 -inf -5267.546800 -8784.373300 5663.944600 -9728.231300 inf
-inf -5373.038600 4282.941600 6245.734200 -5533.975400 nan 8445.713600
+inf -9108.960400 -3796.671200 nan -2363.851300 877.460400 9936.416900
-3480.867400
```

The output from that is:

```
Before sort (29):
   +3023.4218   +9033.9022          nan   -9370.9525   +3088.8849
   +6829.1354      +0.0000      -0.0000         -inf   -5267.5468
   -8784.3733   +5663.9446   -9728.2313         +inf         -inf
   -5373.0386   +4282.9416   +6245.7342   -5533.9754          nan
   +8445.7136         +inf   -9108.9604   -3796.6712          nan
   -2363.8513    +877.4604   +9936.4169   -3480.8674
After sort (29):
          nan          nan          nan         -inf         -inf
   -9728.2313   -9370.9525   -9108.9604   -8784.3733   -5533.9754
   -5373.0386   -5267.5468   -3796.6712   -3480.8674   -2363.8513
      -0.0000      +0.0000    +877.4604   +3023.4218   +3088.8849
   +4282.9416   +5663.9446   +6245.7342   +6829.1354   +8445.7136
   +9033.9022   +9936.4169         +inf         +inf
```